# javascript - if statement excecutes both if and else blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

This is my code:

```
var counter = 0;

function showAddButton() {
  var cnt = document.getElementsByClassName('img-cntnr').length;
  counter++;  // for detecting double excecution in debugger

  if (cnt < 4) {
    $('#div-add').show();
  } else {
    $('#div-add').hide();
  }
}

//someweher in my code
showAddButton();
```

when I call function in my code, JavaScript executes both `$('#div-add').show();` and `$('#div-add').hide();` lines.

I've defined a variable (`counter`) and watched that in debugger for detecting parallel twice call. but there is not any parallel execution and in first call if-statement executes both blocks!

how can I fix that?
Thank You.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki the problem is that both blocks of a conditional statement are executing. Its clear enough.

Comment: it is not possible for both to happen with only one call to showAddButton. something else is happening, which makes this question very unclear.

Comment: The real issue is that hes only posting a portion of the code, and that showAddButton is getting called multiple times

Comment: Try to use console.log inside of if and else blocks to investigate problem.

Comment: If both are executed, it means it is executed at least twice.

Comment: try cleaning your cache and debug using a browser debug tool place a breakpoint on that block of code and check to see how many times it's being called

Comment: That, or something else is calling `$('#div-add').show / hide`

Comment: My wild guess is this code is within an element that is being cloned or moved, thus resetting the counter back to 0 before the next call to showAddButton.

Comment: @Farshad, you need to post all of your code.  1. is there something else incrementing your counter besides the function because clearly you count is to 4.  2. is there anything else that calls showAddButton or hides and shows that div

Comment: i believe, the script is been executed before the selecting html elements.

Comment: try adding two different alerts in both the blocks, eg. alert("if"); and alert("else"); respectively, i tried your code with fewer html elements.. that worked fine for me.. i don't think. both the blocks will be executed, its against the basic programming what we all know.. :)

Comment: @johnny5 as I noticed in my question, I've defined a global variable `counter` to detecting multiple execution. in debugger, I'm running code line by line, and then, in same `counter` value in watch, I can see debugger cursor passes from both blocks of if-else- statement!

Comment: Simple test that would prove things... add a `console.log('foo')` before the if statement and inside of each. it simply isn't possible for both conditions of an if statement to happen within a single run through of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is most likely your if statement is not the logic you want perhaps your < should be a >, because even if you were hitting it multiple times that shouldn't really effect the results of the problem because the only way for the else to hit would be if you count was actually greater than what you expected.

So either something else is hiding the div, something is modifying the class count, or your logic is not what you expected it to be.

However you can try this line of code which will get rid of all the excess logic you have

```
$('#div-add').toggle($('.img-cntnr').length < 4)
```

you can use a boolean in the toggle fuction to set the display

you can see the toggle documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: great! supreme! appreciable! a better one with shorter compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Here look at this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sddm9eyk/1/)

I cannot see any duplicate calls, nor that both blocks of `if/else` are executed in one call.

showAddButton always shows element because it depends on:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('img-cntnr').length;
```

which gets length of how many elements matched `img-cntnr` class. So, unless you are adding elements with that class to the DOM, that count will always be the same.

If you can show us jsFiddle that prints both `show` and `hide` we will have something to go by.

Answer (score -2):

There is definitely something else that is causing the code to run again. What I would do is add a killer to your js and modify the else statement to look like this:

```
var counter = 0;

var killer = false;

function showAddButton() {
  var cnt = document.getElementsByClassName('img-cntnr').length;
  counter++;  // for detecting double excecution in debugger

  if (cnt < 4) {
    $('#div-add').show();
    killer = true
  } else if(killer === false) {
    $('#div-add').hide();
  }
}

//someweher in my code
showAddButton();
```

Comment: don't fix the symptoms... fix the problem.

Comment: dont put bandaids on problems fix them

Comment: Given the limited details he gave us you can't do much more! It still solves the problem!

Comment: don't fix band-aids, put symptoms in their problems

Comment: @ThomasCarnevale what happens if the .img-cntnr class can be added or removed and then he removes one of them and the killer is suppose to be false again?

Comment: You could reset the killer somewhere else in the code. It was more the concept of using a killer instead of just using an else statement was what I was getting at.